# apt -get not being understood

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I installed Kali 2016.2 this morning and haven't been able to install any package using the terminal commands. I don't know how to resolve the issue. Please help. [image: Terminal screenshot with error message.]

Comment: [`apt-get`](http://www.kalitut.com/2014/06/apt-get-command-about-it.html) is a single command, not a command and option. You have a typo there (the space).

Comment: @Adalee - That's the answer: you should submit it as such. It's worth mentioning that `apt install ...` is an alternative to `apt-get install ...`, which is why the error was for an invalid option, rather than a non-existent program.

Answer (score 1):

[`apt-get`](http://www.kalitut.com/2014/06/apt-get-command-about-it.html) is a single command, not a command with options. The space you have in the command shouldn't be there. As you can see in the link, the right way to install a package with `apt-get` is

`apt-get install <package-name>`

This should be prefixed with `sudo` in case you are not the root user (not applicable to your specific case based on the screenshot). Besides the blog post, you can learn about other options how to use `apt-get` from the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get), which can be called from your terminal with `man apt-get`.

The reason you are getting an error about unrecognized option (instead of unrecognized command) is that there is indeed a command called [`apt`](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt.html) which can be used to install packages as well with

`apt install <package-name>`

and this command doesn't understand the combination of options `-g -e -t` (which `-get` is a shorter version of). You can verify the presence of both `apt` and `apt-get` commands with typing `apt` in your terminal and pressing `<TAB>` twice (this lists all commands in the system that begin with `apt`).